# How can I access elements in a LINQ query that is utilizing a groupBy?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two LINQ queries that I want to switch between depending upon the user's selection of a monthly report or yearly report. Before they were working but they were just giving the user a list of results sometimes with 8 of the same deal and instead I'd like to group them by the deal name and display a count of how many are in each group.

```
var sponsorRedemptions = db.PurchasedCardDealRedemptions.Where(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.PurchasedCard.Card.WhiteLabelId == whiteLabelId)
    .Where(pcdr => pcdr.RedemptionDate.Year == year)
    .Where(pcdr => pcdr.RedemptionDate.Month == month)
    .OrderBy(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Vendor.Name)
    .GroupBy(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Name);


var yearponsorRedemptions = db.PurchasedCardDealRedemptions.Where(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.PurchasedCard.Card.WhiteLabelId == whiteLabelId)
      .Where(pcdr => pcdr.RedemptionDate.Year == year)
      .OrderBy(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Vendor.Name)
      .GroupBy(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Name);
```

After I do a selection like this I am having problems accessing columns within that selection that used to work when I just did a .ToList(); on the queries.

```
foreach (var item in sponsorRedemptions)
{
    csv.Append("\n");

    csv.Append(item.PurchasedCardDeal.PurchasedCard.Card.Name + ", " + item.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Vendor.Name + ", " + item.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Name);

    totalRedemptions++;
}
```

Anything after item. is not working I am wondering how I can access the elements of each item in the group and the count of how many items are in each group. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each element in the result of a `GroupBy` is a group - which itself then contains the elements, as well as a key. So you can do something like this:

```
foreach (var group in sponsorRedemptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", item.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal.Vendor.Name);
    }
}
```

As an aside, you only seemed to be using the `PurchasedCardDeal.Deal` part after the `Where` clause, so you might want to project to that:

```
var sponsorRedemptions = db.PurchasedCardDealRedemptions
    .Where(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.PurchasedCard.Card.WhiteLabelId == whiteLabelId)
    .Where(pcdr => pcdr.RedemptionDate.Year == year)
    .Where(pcdr => pcdr.RedemptionDate.Month == month)
    .Select(pcdr => pcdr.PurchasedCardDeal.Deal);
    .OrderBy(deal => deal.Vendor.Name)
    .GroupBy(deal => deal.Name);

foreach (var group in sponsorRedemptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var deal in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", deal.Vendor.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`item` is a collection of elements in the group.

To see the thing you grouped by, use `item.Key`.  To see individual items, use normal ways of accessing collections, such as loops or LINQ methods (eg, `Count()`).